# Are these properties of a Causal Dynamical Triangulation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

I'll preface this by saying I haven't done that much research on the physics of CDT, but I'm interested in procedurally creating graphical representations of these triangulations. Or at least triangulations that satisfy the geometric constraints of a causal dynamic triangulation.

I'll start by listing what I understand to be true. The triangulation can be thought of as existing in a Euclidean space, there are time-slices which are parallel hyperplanes in the space oriented along the direction of time and separated by some set distance, all vertices are on one of these hyperplanes, edges are between two consecutive time-slices, space like edges and time like edges are assumed to each have their own set length.

My first question is whether or not the time-like edge length must be smaller than the space-like one. This seems like it would follow from the fact that edges must connect vertices of consecutive hyperplanes and the fact that if the edge is time-like, the "next" vertex must be inside the light cone of the point it is coming from.

Then there is the question crucial to the development of my algorithm. Assume the dimension is $n+1$ ($n$ spatial dimensions), let $a_t$ be the time-like edge length and $a_s$ be the space-like one. If the time-slices are hyperplanes and they are set apart by a set displacement $t_0$ then, if my premises are correct, a vertex following a time-like edge will lie on $S^{n-1}$ with radius $r_t=\sqrt{a_t^2 - t_0^2}$ centered at the projection of previous point onto the next hyperplane. Likewise with space-like edges but $r_s=\sqrt{a_s^2-t_0^2}$.

Is there anything wrong with my understanding of the geometric constraints? I feel like all I've done is some basic geometry.

Comment: What software are you going to use for this?

Comment: @magma I'm thinking about using Unity, but I'm on Linux so it's pretty buggy

Answer (score 0):

Apart from one "little" thing, you are quite right. They are not embedded in an N dimensional space, but these triangulations are space themselves. You cannot embedd let's say 3 dim CDT configuration in a 3dim space, because you either have to relax the fix length condition, or your triangles will visually go through each other, thus they won't be manifolds anymore.

Yes, the time like links can be longer, or shorter. There are constraints, but you are safe up to alpha = 0.7. Alpha = 0 stands for equal length and negative values denote shorter.

Did you manage to do graphics? I'ld love to see your plots, and would be glad if you could share them.